# Adafruit's LCD doesn't show text

Tags: python

I've just written small python script to operate adafruit's lcd with additional module. Almost every lcd's operation is handled by module. But when I try to print a message on screen or in console, nothing happens. The only thing I can do is to clear the lcd.

python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import time
import sys
from time import time, sleep
import screen_manager
frameperiod=1.0/10
now=time()
nextframe=now+frameperiod
lcd = screen_manager.screen()
lcd.init
lcd.frameperiod = 10
while True:
#fps limiter
#    print (lcd.frame)
    while now<nextframe:
        sleep(nextframe-now)
        now=time()
    nextframe+=frameperiod
   # lcd.process #debug 
    lcd.frame=lcd.frame+1
    lcd.frame=lcd.frame%lcd.frameperiod
```

module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import time
import thread
import socket
import json
import os
import sys
from time import gmtime, strftime
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
# Initialize the LCD using the pins

class screen:
    lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()

    buttons = ( (LCD.SELECT, 0),
                (LCD.LEFT,   1),
                (LCD.UP,     2),
                (LCD.DOWN,   3),
                (LCD.RIGHT,  4) )

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    WS_address = ('172.16.1.2', 14500)
    temp_data = [("",-1,-1),("",-1,-1),("",-1,-1),("",-1,-1)]
    bitbay_data = -1
    button = 0
    is_pressed = 0
    pos = (0,0) # x,y
    menu_height = (0,4)
    frame = 0
    frameperiod = 0
    def Temp_update():
        sock.connect(WS_address)
        temp_data=sock.recv(2048)
        sock.close()
    def Clock():
        print "Clock"
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message('Zegar\n')
        lcd.message(strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        #Force update!
    def Temperature(temp_pos):
        thread.start_new_thread(Temp_update,())
        if temp_pos==0:
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.message('Temperatura')
        else:
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.message(temp_data[temp_pos][0]+'\n')
            lcd.message('T: ' + temp_data[temp_pos][1])
            if temp_data[temp_pos][2]!=-1:
                lcd.message(" H: "+ temp_data[temp_pos][2])
    menu = {
        (0,0) : Clock,
        (1,0) : Temperature,
        (1,1) : Temperature,
        (1,2) : Temperature,
        (1,3) : Temperature,
        (1,4) : Temperature,


    }
    def process():
        print "Process"
     #   lcd.message("debug")
        sleep(100)
        for tbutton in buttons:
            if lcd.is_pressed(tbutton[0]):
                is_pressed=1
        if is_pressed==1: #len(array)
            #move
            if button[1] == 1 and pos[1] == 0 and pos[0]>0:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1 #left
            if button[1] == 4 and pos[1] == 0 and pos[0]<len(menu_height):
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1 #right
            if button[1] == 2 and pos[1]>0:
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1 #up
            if button[1] == 3 and pos[1]<=menu_height[pos[0]]:
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            is_pressed=0
        print pos
        if frame==0:
            menu[pos](pos[1])
        #todo button[1]=1?
        is_pressed=0
    def init():
        lcd.set_color(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Init")
        sleep(1000)
        print "Init"
```

If it's my mistake, I sorry, i'm green in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unfamiliar with Python you are being ambitious to try to develop a big block of code without testing as you go along.

Note the difference between `lcd.init` and what you want which is `lcd.init()`.

Comment: Ok, it turned out there was missing (self) in fuctions definition
But now when it tries to launch function via dictionary (menu[pos](pos[1])) it says that 'menu' is not defined. So I moved menu outside the class, but then it doesn't find functions inside dictionary :/

Comment: @tyrtyrtyrtyr  As I said I think you are being too ambitious.  I would dump all the existing code and start again from scratch, testing each new feature you add.